# AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, get, afnetworking-2

I'm a newbie in iOS development and I'm trying to figure out how to send GET request with AFNetworking.

I used the example provided in [Tutorial on Using AFNetworking 2.0](http://samwize.com/2014/05/10/tutorial-on-using-afnetworking-2-dot-0/) and placed it in main expecting a error:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://samwize.com/api/poos/"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                 }];
```

...and I've got nothing, so I tried to point to the webservice that returns a valid JSON and also got nothing. Why none of blocks (success or failure) are executed?

Comment: have you called this method somewhere in 'viewdidload' or somewhere in  button action ??
and if yes,
what is your error??

Comment: Don't put that in the main function.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need any parameter?

Comment: @AdamPro13, thanks, I'm aware of that. Just trying to test the functionality.

Comment: @Andrea, In a fact I do, but I just want at least get some error to proceed with this.

Comment: Are you calling that method from any particular thread?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not execute blocks (success or failure) beacause somthing went wrong.
but if you use try catch block then it will go into catch block try once.
**code:**

try {

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://samwize.com/api/poos/"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                 }];

}@catch (NSException *exception) {
**// you will get error here**
}
```

Comment: Just did and nothing was raised. That's very strange. I just get successful code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use following `function` and just send your `URL` in `Argument`

```
- (void)callWebservice : (NSString *)strURL{

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL urlWithEncoding:strURL]];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"" parameters:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:180];
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                         {
                                             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                                              NSLog(@"Success");

                                         } failure:^ (NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id json){
                                             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                                             NSLog(@"Failure");
                                         }];
    [GlobalManager setOperationInstance:operation];
    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was strange, I just created another project (iOS instead of OSX) and called the same code from the IBAction and it worked easily. In Podfile I specified a new version of AFNetworking (2.5 instead of 2.4). I don't know if this is relevant.
Thank you everyone for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to do that.

```
     @try {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:stringURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     }
   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
     }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"Exception - %@", [exception debugDescription]);
      }
  @finally {
     }
```

And make sure you have  a valid JSON.